# Firebase: How to check query is finished? (swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

I'm trying to display spinner while querying data from firebase, and hide it when the query result is returned. 
is there any way to know if the query has finished retrieving all data? ?

```
self.handle = self.ref.child("users").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print ("snapshot exist")
            print (snapshot.childrenCount)
        }
        else {
                print ("snapshot doesn't exist")
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

When the callback block of a `.Value` observer is invoked, it gets all data that is currently known for that location. So you can hide the spinner in the block:

```
self.handle = self.ref.child("users").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    // TODO: hide spinner here
    if snapshot.exists() {
        print ("snapshot exist")
        print (snapshot.childrenCount)
    }
    else {
        print ("snapshot doesn't exist")
    }
})
```

Keep in mind though that a Firebase observer keeps synchronizing data, so you block may be run multiple times.

Comment: great, thanks for the clarification. I thought the block is called each time a child is fetched.

Comment: Sort of. `.Value` causes it to be called once, with the node and all of it's children. If any piece of data in that node (including anything in it's children) is changed, it gets called again, providing all of the data _again_. So, if a child is added, it will be called again. But if no children are added, it is only called once.

You may be thinking of .ChildAdded, which is called _n_ times, where _n_ is the number of children. It is then also called if any children are added.